# VBA Range.Find Method return Nothing when value exists

Tags: excel, find, vba

I am trying to get the address of the cell which contains a certain value:

```
dim MinAdrress as Range
Set MinAddress = DetractRow.Find(Min_1, , xlValues, xlWhole)
```

`Min_1` is 0.23, and the `DetractRow` range contains the following values:

```
30% 26% 23% 27% -7%
```

So MinAddress should be the 3rd cell in the range. However, in the Locals window I see it as `Nothing`. I also tried without the optional paramaters (`xlValues, xlWhole`), same result. Many thanks for any input

Comment: As far as I understand, the `Find` function matches the cell values as they are formatted by the cell. This would find your value, for example, `rng.Cells.Find("23%", rng.Cells(1), xlValues, xlWhole, xlRows, xlNext, True)`.

Comment: @Ambie Correct; if I force the argument, it returns the correct address. So this then becomes a problem of either the `Min_1` into percentage or the cells into a number...

Comment: Well, I'm allergic to cell formatting and the `Find` function, so I'd read the column into an array of variants and just run a `For` loop on each cell to match `Value2` with your item - 4 lines of code and done.

Comment: I'll put the code in an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, I believe the `Find` function will match the value of a cell as it is formatted by that cell. So *0.23* won't find *23%* unless you do a bit of extra work. This, for example, would work: `rng.Cells.Find("23%", rng.Cells(1), xlValues, xlWhole, xlRows, xlNext, True)`. I've heard of various, quite extravagant, actions people have taken, esp. when it comes to finding dates (I've even heard of people reading the cell formats, clearing them, and then rewriting them at the conclusion of the `Find`).

I'm not a big fan of the `Find` function. One can go to all the effort, for example, of creating a value as a `String` that would be a match for the specific cell format, only to find that you or someone else decided one more decimal place would be better. It doesn't take a big depth charge to sink that `Find` sub.

I still favour reading the values into an array and `For ... Next` looping, especially as `Value2` gives you the option, for example, of searching for dates in their `Long` form so there's no risk of formatting issues.

Here's the code for you:

```
Dim v As Variant
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long

'If DetractRow range is just one column
v = DetractRow.Value2
For r = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
    If v(r, 1) = Min_1 Then
        MsgBox "Gotcha at index " & CStr(r)
        Exit For
    End If
Next

'If DetractRow range is just one row
v = DetractRow.Value2
For c = 1 To UBound(v, 2)
    If v(1, c) = Min_1 Then
        MsgBox "Gotcha at index " & CStr(c)
        Exit For
    End If
Next

'If DetractRow range is more than one row and column
v = DetractRow.Value2
For c = 1 To UBound(v, 2)
    For r = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
        If v(r, c) = Min_1 Then
            MsgBox "Gotcha at index " & CStr(r) & _
                    ", " & CStr(c)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```